# Vue <teleport> in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

While designing client-rendering SPA, <teleport to="body"> of Vue3 works well.
I can teleport dialog component to <body>.

```
<--! dialog component example-->

<template>
  <teleport to="body">
    <div class="dialog">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </teleport>
</template>
```

However, it's failed when I try to use the same way in Nuxt static mode.

Does Nuxt support "teleport" method?

Is there any other workaround dealing with teleport in Nuxt static application?

Comment: There is maybe no SSR functionality to the teleport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portals/Teleport arrived with Vue 3. This is not yet supported in Nuxt, as it is still running on v2. If necessary, you can likely find alternative third party packages for this in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand what you're looking for but one solution is using `<ClientOnly>`. Most of the time we only need to render Modal in [client-side](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components/#the-client-only-component) (without SSR) anyway.

```
<template>
  <div class="modal_container">
    <ClientOnly>
      <Teleport to="body">
        <div class="modal">
          Hello World
        </div>
      </Teleport>
    </ClientOnly>
  </div>
</template>
```